# How do I refer to an attribute of an object in a list, by using a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, adventure

I'm writing a text adventure game and I'm trying to take an input for an object in a room, search for it in the objects list, then take that object and append it to the inventory (inv) list. I need to search for the object using the the input of its' name, which is one of the attributes.

```
class room():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.objects = []

class player(room):
    def __init__(self, name, inv):
        self.name = name
        self.inv = []

class things(room):
    def __init__(self, name, is_weapon):
        self.name = name
        self.weapon = is_weapon



currentRoom = center
objLen = len(currentRoom.objects)
if currentRoom.objects:
    for x in range(len(currentRoom.objects)):
        print("Objects here: ",currentRoom.objects[x].name)
    pickUp = input("Would you like to take any objects: ")

    for a in range(0,objLen):
        if pickUp.upper() == currentRoom.objects.name:
            ind = currentRoom.objects.index(pickUp.upper().name)
            Andy.inv.append(currentRoom.objects[ind])
            currentRoom.objects.pop[ind]
        else:
            print("Object not found in this room!")
```

Comment: ***`class player(room):`, `class things(room):`***: A `player` or `things` are not a `room`? Both can be reside in a `room` but shouldn't inherit from it.

Comment: ***refer ... an object in a list, by using a string?***: In your case, `ind = a`. `a` is the index of the object matching `pickUp.upper() == currentRoom.objects.name`

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
for a in range(0,objLen):
        if pickUp.upper() == currentRoom.objects[a].name:

            Player.inv.append(currentRoom.objects[a])
            currentRoom.objects.pop(a)
```